# Send python output (json output) to telegraf over http_listener_v2

Tags: python, python-3.x, influxdb, telegraf, telegraf-inputs-plugin

I am trying to post test_data output from below python script (abc.py) to telegraf over http_listener_v2.

```
abc.py
------
import requests
url = "https://testazure.local/telegraf"
test_data = {'key1': 'value1'}

op = requests.post(url, data = test_data)
print(op.test_data)
```

Here is the snippets from my **telegraf.conf** file for inputs .

```
telegraf.conf
-----------------
[[inputs.http_listener_v2]]
#   ## Address and port to host HTTP listener on
# methods = ["POST", "PUT"]
   data_format = "json"
```

Not sure , if i am passing all the requsite details to the input plugin .

Getting connection error in an attempt to execute my python script . Any advise /help would be highly appreciated .

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "abc.py", line 6, in <module>
    x = requests.post(url, data = test_data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 119, in post
    return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)

requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host'testazure.local', port=443): 
Max retries exceeded with url: /telegraf (Caused by 
NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f9eb8c72438>: 
Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))
```

Comment: your url should probably be just `localhost`, a real IP, or domain that you control, not whatever "testazure.local" is supposed to be ; you're probably running into a firewall issue

Answer (score 1):

I think your url needs http and not https. I have this exact setup and I am looking for an answer as well.

Actually seeing your question, I was able to solve my problem. I had the following code... notice the post method arguments... `json`

```
host = "rpi4-2GB"
port = 8080
path = "/telegraf"
weather_dict = data
url_str = "http://{}:{}{}".format(host, port, path)
http_res = requests.post(url=url_str, json=dumps(weather_dict))
```

`>>> http_res.status_code`

> 400

after reading your question here, I changed my kwarg to `data`

```
url_str = "http://{}:{}{}".format(host, port, path)
http_res = requests.post(url=url_str, data=dumps(weather_dict))
```

`>>> http_res.status_code`

> 204

204 is the proper value to get back from my experience with telegraph's `http_listener_v2` plugin.

Comment: if you use `json=` you don't have to use `json.dumps()` as it is already dictionary